# Java iText: text below image

Tags: java, itext, pdfptable

in a PdfPCell i'd like to put multiple images, and a text below each image.
i tried with this code:

```
   private PdfPTable tabellaRighe() throws BadElementException, MalformedURLException, IOException, DocumentException {
    int[] cellWidth = {500, 95};
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidths(cellWidth);
    table.setTotalWidth(PageSize.A4.getWidth() - 45);
    table.setLockedWidth(true);
    PdfPCell cell;
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setBorderWidth(0);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Image image = Image.getInstance(imgNd);
        image.scaleToFit(300, 135);
        Phrase ph = new Phrase();
        ph.add(new Chunk(image, 0, 0, true));
        ph.add("CIAO");
        p.add(ph);
    }
    cell.addElement(p);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setBorderWidthBottom(1);
    cell.setBorderWidthLeft(1);
    cell.setBorderWidthRight(1);
    cell.setBorderWidthTop(1);
    table.addCell(cell);
  }
```

but the text is not below the image, but shifted to the right.
how can I put the text below each image?

Answer (score 0):

Add  `\n` before and after text.

```
ph.add("\nCIAO\n");
```

**\n** produce new line.

Comment: meanwhile, thanks for the reply.
the problem is that the image have to be inline.